# Date Formula using values from a picklist

Tags: salesforce

I need to create a formula for a date field where the date field would be auto-populated based on another Date Field + a selected Picklist Value.
The formula for the new date field is

**New Date Field = Old Date Field + No of Years**

Again, the "Number of Years" comes from a picklist, which is a text field.

[Example of Picklist HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y1rS.png)

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What are the picklist values (your screenshot shows labels visible in UI but what are their API names/values when you view the picklist in setup)

Assuming they're the same you should experiment with something like this. Start with a formula with text or number type, work till you're happy with intermediate product, then make final formula with date type.

1. `LEFT(TEXT(Number_of_years__c),1)` should give you "5" as a text. If you have more than 1 digit you may need `LEFT(...,2)` and maybe `SUBSTITUTE` around it to cut extra spaces out.
2. Then call `VALUE()` to convert text "5" to number `5`.
3. Finally `ADDMONTHS(My_Date__c, 12 * your_complex_formula_here)` should do the trick

It'd be simpler if your picklist values were just "1", "2", "3" (labels can stay as is) but you can't always change that without changing other places that rely on this picklist so...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that if you select **3 Yrs then picklist will return 3 as value**.

Integer picklist_value = "Selected option value from picklist";

1. Date newDate = Date.newInstance(**oldDate.year()+ picklist_value**, oldDate.month(), oldDate.Day());

Hope this solution will help.